# What do + and * mean in regex?

Tags: regex

I got an answer to my question here: [How do I know if a file is tab or space delimited in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/699253/how-to-find-out-if-file-is-tab-or-space-delimited-in-perl/699256#699256)

but it would really help me if someone could break down the regex and explain what is going on and why it wont work on the last line of the file.

```
~/^(\d+\s+)+?$/
```

I thought the above had '+' in theback so if i add '*' it will work because * means zero or more...but that did not work

Comment: You might find you get a better response if you update your original question. I see, BTW, that you asked some of the answerers on the original question to explain the regex only 39 minutes ago... give them time to respond! :-)

Comment: The '?' at the end of that regex serves no purpose; there's no point in making a quantifier non-greedy if it has to match all the way to the end of the input anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Regex: /^(\d+\s+)+?$/
Parts:  1  2  3  456
```

1. Match from the start of a line
2. Find one or more numbers
3. Followed by one or more spaces (or tabs)
4. Find one or more of **2** and **3**
5. But don't be greedy in that match (that is, stop when you can, don't keep going until you can't)
6. Match the end of a line.

It should match a string of an entire line of space or tab separated numbers. I'm not exactly sure about why it'd be failing on the last line.. perhaps there's no space character at the end? Since each number must be followed by at least one space, that might be it.

Answer (score 0):

In fact the original regex does not accept empty lines, that's probably why it does not work on the last line of your file (a link to an example file would be nice). It should look like this:

```
perl -ne 'if ($_=~/^(\d+\s+)*$/){print "yep\n";}'
```

Another way might be to just check for all the characters to be either whitespace or a digit.

When accepting empty lines:

```
perl -ne 'if ($_=~/^[\s\d]*$/){print "yep\n";}'
```

When not accepting empty lines:

```
perl -ne 'if ($_=~/^[\s\d]+$/){print "yep\n";}'
```